# Simple javascript unity converter not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get a simple converter to work. None of the input fields work at the moment.
Can I get the price variable like I did through PHP?

```
<h1 style='font-size:46px'>1 DOLLAR = <p id="currentprice" type="number"><?php $url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"; $json = file_get_contents($url); $json_data = json_decode($json, true); $price = $json_data["rates"]["BRL"]; echo $price; ?></p></h1>
How many Dollars?
<input oninput='finalAmountUSD()' onchange='finalAmountUSD()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number'  class="buy buyinput form-control" id='usdamount' required value='0.00000000' tabindex="1" />
How many BRL?
<input oninput='finalAmountBRL()' onchange='finalAmountBRL()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number'  class="buy buyinput form-control" id='brlamount' required value='0.00' tabindex="2" />

<script>
function finalAmountUSD()
{
  x = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;
  y = document.getElementById('usdamount').value;
  z = document.getElementById('brlamount').value;
  document.getElementById('usdamount').value = x * z;
}
function finalAmountBRL()
{
  x = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;
  y = document.getElementById('usdamount').value;
  z = document.getElementById('brlamount').value;
  document.getElementById('brlamount').value = x * y;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is meant by `atm` here.

Comment: @manikantgautam — https://www.acronymfinder.com/ATM.html — At The Moment

Comment: try `var x =document.getElementById("currentprice").innerHTML` instead of value.

Comment: @manikantgautam — Why? There is no element with the id "me" in the code.

Comment: @Quentin it was typo error.

Comment: @manikantgautam Thanks, but that didn't work. Both input fields are not accepting any input and will only display "0".

Answer (score 0):

```js
function finalAmountUSD()
{
  x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('currentprice').value);
  z = parseFloat(document.getElementById('brlamount').value);
   
  document.getElementById('usdamount').value = x * z;
}
function finalAmountBRL()
{
   x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('currentprice').value);
   z = parseFloat(document.getElementById('usdamount').value);
   
  document.getElementById('brlamount').value = x * z;
}
```

```html
<h1 style='font-size:46px'>1 DOLLAR = <input id="currentprice" type="number" value="0.7">BRL</p></h1>
How many Dollars?
<input onblur='finalAmountBRL()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number'  class="buy buyinput form-control" id='usdamount' required value='0.00000000' tabindex="1" />
<br/>
How many BRL?
<input onblur='finalAmountUSD()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number'  class="buy buyinput form-control" id='brlamount' required value='0.00' tabindex="2" />
```

Your problem is that you are trying to get value from

```
 <p id="currentprice" type="number"></p>
```

in your code

```
x = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;
```

currentprice is a p and cannot have value. Try to change it with a readonly input

One more suggestion: since money value is not integer you better use parseFloat on all your results. Also, I think that you need to use use functions only onblur   event.

Comment: I changed it to `<input readonly id="currentprice" type="number"><?php $url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"; $json = file_get_contents($url); $json_data = json_decode($json, true); $price = $json_data["rates"]["BRL"]; echo $price; ?> />` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example and use to your end.

```
<script>
//# <-- access with id
//. <-- access with a class name
var value1 = $("#currentprice").html(); // get values from html object
var value2 = $("#currentprice2").val(); // get values from input
alert("Value: "+value1);
</script>
```

Don't repeat id name or you will have errors.